# How to change storyboard flow

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have to modify the flow of ViewControllers displayed based on a storyboard in a legacy app.

Let´s say the storyboard says to display screens as follow:

```
screen A -> screen B -> screen C -> screen D
```

Now the modification is that depending on a particular condition the screen C should not be displayed. Let say, if the condition is true the screen C is displayed otherwise it is not and screen D is directly displayed.

The flow should be:

```
                        /-------false--\ 
                       /                \
                      /   true           \
screen A -> screen B ---------> screen C ----> screen D
```

I create a segue between screen B and screen D. If the condition is true I do nothing (screen C and then screen D are displayed), if the condition is false I call the segue in the ViewController for screen B:

```
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "DirectlyDisplayScreenD", sender: self)
```

It is almost working... the screen C is displayed a half second and then comes the screen D.

I am a beginner with iOS, is what I did at least in principle correct ?

Is there an obvious reason why is the screen C shortly displayed ? Is it because of the storyboard ? or calling a segue is not enough ? or does it means that the ViewController for screen C is instantiated somewhere in the code ?

Is there a method to remove a ViewController of a storyboard ? I found the method [instantiateViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard) but I did not find a method "removeViewController"

Comment: do you hook the button as the source of the segue or  VCB

Comment: if you do nothing and the screen is displayed, then there must be a triggered segue by a button directly set in the storyboard

Comment: I think you've copied the button and added new action to the button but the old action is still there. After tapping the button it calls both methods (the new one and the old one). In the storyboard right click on the button and check how many actions it calls.

Comment: can you share the code about performSegue? And be sure about the button "Sent Events" on storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself. I removed the legacy segue and re-built it again taking care of giving him a name. After that the application follows the flows I wish.

Thanks for all the suggestions!!